# Activiti - Error when migration process instance from Activiti 5.21.0 to Activiti 6

Tags: java, migration, activiti

I have handled migration activiti from 5.21.0 to 6.0.0 by guide from https://www.activiti.org/migration.html
(I have updated file `activiti-rest/WEB-INF/classes/activiti-custom-context.xml` to set activiti5CompatibilityEnabled and activiti5CompatibilityHandlerFactory

```
<bean id="activiti5CompabilityFactory" class="org.activiti.compatibility.spring.SpringActiviti5CompatibilityHandlerFactory" />
<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
.........
<property name="activiti5CompatibilityEnabled" value="true" />
<property name="activiti5CompatibilityHandlerFactory" ref="activiti5CompabilityFactory" />
</bean>
```

and copy activiti5-compatibility-6.0.0.jar, activiti5-engine-6.0.0.jar, activiti5-spring-6.0.0.jar, activiti5-spring-compatibility-6.0.0.jar to activiti-rest's libs and activiti-app's libs)

and I had a active process instance in old version as below

[image]

after migration, I still got a this process instance, but when I submit user task, and service task execute and throw BpmnError, the BoundaryEvent can not catch this exception, I got an error in log

```
03:29:59,686 [activiti-async-job-executor-thread-2] ERROR org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext - Error while closing command context
org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Programmatic error: no parent scope execution found for boundary event
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.BoundaryEventActivityBehavior.executeInterruptingBehavior(BoundaryEventActivityBehavior.java:85)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.BoundaryEventActivityBehavior.trigger(BoundaryEventActivityBehavior.java:56)
```

**Programmatic error: no parent scope execution found for boundary event at BoundaryEventActivityBehavior.executeInterruptingBehavior(BoundaryEventActivityBehavior.java:85)**
=> I don't know why BoundaryEvent can't find parent (service task - it work correctly on old version).

Answer (score 0):

As the [Activiti User Guide](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnBoundaryErrorEvent) defines the **Boundary Error Event** -

> Defining a boundary error event makes most sense on an embedded subprocess, or a call activity, as a subprocess creates a scope for all activities inside the subprocess. Errors are thrown by error end events. Such an error will propagate its parent scopes upwards until a scope is found on which a boundary error event is defined that matches the error event definition.
>
> When an error event is caught, the activity on which the boundary
>   event is defined is destroyed, also destroying all current executions
>   within (e.g. concurrent activities, nested subprocesses, etc.).
>   Process execution continues following the outgoing sequence flow of
>   the boundary event.

**Workaround:**
Try a Gateway after your service task to check if the condition to complete the process is met or not - [explanation](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/219492-how-to-trigger-the-error-boundary-event-in-the-task)